# How to compare the previous index with current index on run time in ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, iterator, listiterator

I am checking on the run time that does previous index of `ArrayList` has the same values as current index has. If previous value is same as compare to the current value then I don't want to add again into the List. How can I do that? Please find below the code which I have been trying:

```
List<EventDto> liveEvents = new ArrayList<EventDto>();
EventDto liveTvEventDto = null;
List<CustomerEventDetails> customerDetails = odsRepository.getEventDetails(countryCode, customerId);        
if (customerDetails.size() > 0) {           
    for (CustomerEventDetails customerData : customerDetails) {
        liveTvEventDto = new EventDto();
        liveTvEventDto.setCountryCode(customerData.getCountryCode());
        liveTvEventDto.setCustomerId(customerData.getCustomerId());

        ListIterator<EventDto> listIterator =  liveEvents.listIterator();

        if (listIterator.previousIndex() == -1) {
            listIterator.next();    

            int i =listIterator.previousIndex();
            System.out.println("listIterator:"+liveEvents.get(i));
            if (!(StringUtility.trimmedOrEmptyIfNull(liveEvents.get(i).getCustomerId()).equals(StringUtility.trimmedOrEmptyIfNull(liveTvEventDto.getCustomerId()))
                                && StringUtility.trimmedOrEmptyIfNull(liveEvents.get(i).getCountryCode()).equals(StringUtility.trimmedOrEmptyIfNull(liveTvEventDto.getCountryCode()))))
                liveEvents.add(liveTvEventDto);
        }
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Why not use a normal loop instead of an enhanced for loop?

Comment: How can i use that loop ?

Comment: I've added an answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use an iterator inside. Just get the last index using the `size()` method.

```
for (CustomerEventDetails customerData : customerDetails) {
    liveTvEventDto = new EventDto();
    // Set member variables

    if (liveEvents.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Last Object: " + liveEvents.get(liveEvents.size() - 1));

        if (/* Logic for checking if the objects are NOT equal */)
            liveEvents.add(liveTvEventDto);
    } else {
        liveEvents.add(liveTvEventDto);
    }
}
```

Note: Instead of using `ArrayList`, you could use a `HashSet` with the logic for equality in the `equals()` method of the object.

Comment: Can you please give example of this code with HashSet?

Comment: Sorry for the updates. Use the `equals()` method of the object. This seems to be a good example ->
 https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-hashcode-equals-contract-set-contains/

Comment: How can a size be greate then 0 before adding it to list :) 
   if (liveEvents.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Last Object: " + liveEvents.get(liveEvents.size() - 1));

        if (/* Logic for checking if the objects are NOT equal */)
            liveEvents.add(liveTvEventDto);
    }

Comment: My bad. Just add another else block which adds to the list.